# Determine type during json deserialize

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm working on a protocol in which the receiver will receive json messages of certain specified custom types (currently 5, but could be 10-20). I'm struggling to come up with an optimal/fast solution which will automatically deserialize the json and return the correct type of object.

Example:

```
public class MessageA
{
    public string Message;
} 

public class MessageB
{
    public int value;
}

public class MessageC
{
    public string ValueA;
    public string ValueB;
}
```

Ideally, the method should be like

```
 Object Deserialize(string json);
```

and it will return one of the three message types OR null - in case there was a parsing error/the json didn't match any of the predefined type.

UPDATE: I have control over sender/receiver as well as the protocol design.

Comment: Are you the sender, reciever, or do you have control over the content of both?

Comment: my solution was to send over the class name as a string in the Json file 
Deseralize the first time as a JObject to determine the type and the second time to create your object

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It would be helpful if the message could specify its type. Otherwise you have to infer it from some property or another.

You could use a message wrapper class when serializing, like this:

```
public class MessageWrapper<T>
{
    public string MessageType { get { return typeof(T).FullName; } }
    public T Message { get; set; }
}
```

So if you have a class `Name` with a `First` and `Last` property, you could serialize it like this:

```
var nameMessage = new MessageWrapper<Name>();
nameMessage.Message = new Name {First="Bob", Last = "Smith"};
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nameMessage);
```

The serialized JSON is

```
{"MessageType":"YourAssembly.Name","Message":{"First":"Bob","Last":"Smith"}}
```

When deserializing, first deserialize the JSON as this type:

```
public class MessageWrapper
{
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
    public object Message { get; set; }
}

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageWrapper>(serialized);
```

Extract the message type from the `MessageType` property.

```
var messageType = Type.GetType(deserialized.MessageType);
```

Now that you know the type, you can deserialize the `Message` property.

```
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
    Convert.ToString(deserialized.Message), messageType);
```

`message` is an `object`, but you can cast it as `Name` or whatever class it actually is.

Comment: Nice answer, can it be casted from var message to "Name"?, of course, without make it explicit as DeserializeObject<Name>()

Comment: I was trying a similar approach, but tried to cast the `object Message` to a concrete class and that didn't work.  The trick as you pointed out is to convert the property `Message.ToString()` first then deserialize that JSON string to your concrete class.

Answer (score 3):

```
var log = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Log>(File.ReadAllText("log.example.json");

public class Log
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MessageConverter))]
    public object[] Messages { get; set; }
}


public class MessageA
{
    public string Message;
}
public class MessageB
{
    public int value;
}
public class MessageC
{
    public string ValueA;
    public string ValueB;
}

public class MessageConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object ReadMessage(JObject jobject)
        {
            if (jobject.Property("Message") != null)
                return jobject.ToObject<MessageA>(serializer);
            if (jobject.Property("value") != null)
                return jobject.ToObject<MessageB>(serializer);
            if (jobject.Property("ValueA") != null)
                return jobject.ToObject<MessageC>(serializer);
            throw new Exception("Type is not recognized");
        }

        var jarray = JArray.Load(reader);
        return jarray.Select(jitem => ReadMessage((JObject)jitem)).ToArray();
    }


    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Json example:

```
{
  "Messages":
  [
    {"Message": "System halted"},
    {"value": 42},
    {"ValueA": "Bob", "ValueB": "Smith"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are familiar with the factory pattern, you could use factory(s) and include a "Type" property as part of the json, let's call it `_t`.

You can either parse the json string yourself and find the `_t` property's value, deserialise it to a `dynamic` and get `jsonObj._t` or have a simple `class` with only a `_t` field solely to deserialise the json into initially.

Then you can pass this `string` representing the C# Type to the factory and get a json deserialiser for that `Type`.

You can then make all of your outgoing and incoming calls add and process the `_t` parameter respectively, so that new types are easy to add in future, by just adding and registering the serialisers/deserialisers you need for that `Type` with the factory(s).

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can check if the JSON string contains a class-specific Property name. Fast and easy!

Comment: Did you read the previous answers? One of them suggests the same, but with good code samples