# Using Kestrel and middleware how to figure out the class type that was passed in from a Post or Put request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware, .net-8.0, kestrel-http-server

I am using .NET 8 and Kestrel. I am trying to get the class type for any Post or Put requests.

My endpoint code looks something like this:

```
endpoints.MapPost($"{_basePath}/registerMyObject", [AllowAnonymous] async ([FromBody] MyOject myObject) =>
 {
   // my code
 }
```

My middleware looks something like:

```
public class ValidateModelMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private ITokenService _tokenService;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;


    public ValidateModelMiddleware([FromServices] ITokenService tokenService, [FromServices] IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _tokenService = tokenService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {

        if (context.Request.Method == "POST" || context.Request.Method == "PUT")
        {
               // I need to figure out the type that was passed in.  For instance 
        }
     }
```

So when a registerMyObject request is received I want to get the Type MyOject so that I can deserilize that json text directly into that class.  And if a different Post / Put request is used and it has a different class type then I want to get that corresponding type. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? What is `endpoints`?

Comment: I'd deeply recommend not mixing types for an API like this.   That said, this has been asked and answered many times e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638741/deserialising-json-to-derived-types-in-asp-net-web-api https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679972/determine-type-during-json-deserialize

Comment: @possum as far as I understand that those solutions require some distinctive features for different types (typename, different fields) which possibly is not a case for OP.

Comment: Ok looking at the comments and suggestions below there doesn't seem to be a way to pass this type ([FromBody] MyOject myObject) from the first section of code into my Middleware.  Is that correct?

Comment: @ashlar64 either I don't understand you or my answer does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose which type to de-serialize depending on if the jsonstring "keys" matches which class type fileds. For instance:
If there are `ClassA` and `ClassB` both implement `MyObject`.

```
    public class ClassA  :MyObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; } 
    }
    public class ClassB : MyObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }
```

You could use following code to get a "classResult" string which matches jsonstring.

```
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            var classResult = "";
            //Get JsonString
            var bodyStr = "";
            using (StreamReader reader
                      = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
            {
                bodyStr = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            //Parse to JObject and get the keys
            var jobject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bodyStr);
            var keys = jobject.Properties().Select(p => p.Name);

            //Get all types implement "MyObject"
            var parenttype = typeof(MyObject);
            var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(p => parenttype.IsAssignableFrom(p));

            //Compare which type matches keys
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (Match(keys, type))
                {
                    classResult=type.Name;
                }
            }

            await next(context);
        }

        //Method to compare if keys matches all the fields of a Class type
        private bool Match(IEnumerable<string>? keys,Type type)  
        {
            var fieldNames =type .GetProperties().Select(field => field.Name);
            if (!keys.Except(fieldNames).Any() && !fieldNames.Except(keys).Any())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: TBH looks brittle to me. As far as I understand you are trying to guess the type based on passed fields which can have different problems.

Answer (score 0):

Without full setup it is hard to tell how exactly you need to handle the requirement.

If you are using Minimal APIs then you can leverage [endpoint filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/min-api-filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#validate-an-object-with-a-filter) (for example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75745058/2501279)):

```
app.MapPost("/reports", (ReportDTO activityReport) => ...)
    .AddEndpointFilter(async (context, next) =>
    {
        // collection will contain ReportDTO activityReport itself:
        IList<object?> mappedArguments = context.Arguments;
        return await next(context);
    });
```

If you want this to be a middleware then for endpoint routing you use `IEndpointFeature` (middleware should be registered in appropriate place, also note that for controllers handling can be different):

```
// lambda is analog for you InvokeAsync method
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // TODO: check if POST/PUT
    var endpointFeature = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>();
    var endpointMetadataCollection = endpointFeature.Endpoint.Metadata;
    var acceptsMetadata = endpointMetadataCollection.GetMetadata<AcceptsMetadata>();
    var requestType = acceptsMetadata.RequestType; // typeof(ReportDTO)
    // ...
    await next();
});
```

Obviously first approach should be better in terms of perfromance since you will not need to buffer and bind data multiple times.